# is it possible to call a jsp available in a different project by another project in the same workspace

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I have two projects in my workspace: projectA, projectB. The web-flow of projectA has got the following:

```
  <view-state id="hello" view="projectA/firstJSP" >
  </view-state>

<action-state id="checkingvalues">
  <evaluate expression="somethingIsthere" />
     <transition on="success" to="hello" />
     <transition on="error" to="bye" />
</action-state>
```

Its all working fine. The thing is:
if I add the following to the projectA'flow.xml then, it is not working

```
<view-state id="bye" view="projectB/someJSP" >
  </view-state>
```

Here, someJSP.jsp is in projectB(path is:/projectB/WebContent/WEB-INF/common/files/someJSP.jsp)
 and  firstJSP.jsp is in projectA(path is:/projectA/WebContent/WEB-INF/common/gifts/firstJSP.jsp)

So is it possible to call projectB's jsp in projectA's web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not allowed. At the end everything (classes, jps, htmls ..) is packed into a war file that is separated from other wars.

Comment: But it is possible to redirect from the javascript of one jsp in projectA to another jsp in projectB, right??
if(eventName == 'redirect'){
    document.location.href="projectB/common/someJSP";
}

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible.

See some examples here:

http://www.jonathanhui.com/spring-web-flow-web-flow-definiation

In your case you probably want to use something like the following:

```
<view-state id="bye"
    view="externalRedirect:serverRelative:projectB/someJSP">
```

Although as I guess you would want to end the flow at this point then the following might be better:

```
<action-state id="checkingvalues">
  <evaluate expression="somethingIsthere" />
     <transition on="success" to="hello" />
     <transition on="error" to="bye" />
</action-state>

<end-state id="bye" view="externalRedirect:serverRelative:projectB/someJSP"/>
```

Comment: this is not using jsp from other project, but redirecting to other view (which under the hood uses this jsp), but it is redirect

Comment: WTF? From his comment to your answer, it is clear the user is not asking about using a JSP from another project but defining a WebFlow view state which redirects to a page external to the current context.

Comment: the original question was about using jsp, not doing redirect to other application. I think it is obvious you can do redirect.